# onbeforeunload to trigger shopping cart abandonment

Tags: php, onbeforeunload

Is the 'onbeforeunload' event 100% consistent, effective and worthy of using as a trigger for a shopping cart abandonment campaign?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? With onbeforeunload you will have some problems with browsers like Opera. Try to play with serverside sessions, if possible.

Comment: Do you want to abandon the shopping cart every time the user leaves a page?

Comment: I am new to shopping cart abandonment. So i'm trying to figure out the best approach. Write now i have it set up so everytime a user hits their shopping cart, basically a timer starts and if they dont order in say 30 minutes, then their sent an email. I'm just worried i'm not bringing in enough back end logic of their session, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is 100% reliable -- someone could just hit the power switch -- but it's good.

That being said, assume that it will fail sometimes.  Use it more as a convenience for your customers than as a mission-critical piece of functionality.

Comment: Yeah that is what i was figuring.